# What is a conjugacy class of reflection?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have a problem to do, asking to show that $D_{2n}$ has two conjugacy classes of reflections if n is even, but only one if n is odd.

My question is, what is a conjugacy class of reflection?

I have seen that there is a solution to this question on this site, but I don't want to lose the value of the question by looking up the solution.

Thanks

Comment: What is the definition you are using for the group?

Comment: $D_{2n}$ is the Dihedral group of order 2n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reflection of the plane is a linear transformation (ok, it could be affine, but assume that the center of the regular $n$-gon is at the origin) such that it has two orthogonal eigenspaces, one belonging to eigenvalue $+1$ and the other to eigenvalue $-1$. These properties are invariant under conjugation by orthogonal transformations, so any conjugate of a reflection is another reflection.

If the eigenspace of $\lambda=+1$ (=the line that you reflect w.r.t) of a reflection $s$ intersects the polygon at the points $P$ and $Q$, and $g$ is any symmetry of the $n$-gon, then
$gsg^{-1}$ is the reflection w.r.t. the line connecting the points $g(P)$ and $g(Q)$.

If $n$ is odd, then for any reflection $r\in D_{2n}$ one of the points $P,Q$ is a vertex and the other is the midpoint of an edge opposite to that vertex. Because $D_{2n}$ acts transitively on the set of vertices, all the vertices (and hence also all the corresponding midpoints) occur as $PQ$-pairs. Thus there is only a single conjugacy class of reflections.

OTOH if $n$ is even, then both $P$ and $Q$ are either vertices or both are midpoints of an edge. The group $D_{2n}$ does not mix these two kinds of points. For example if $P$ is a vertex, then so is $g(P)$ for all $g\in D_{2n}$. But again $D_{2n}$ acts transitively on both vertices and midpoints, so we get two conjugacy classes of reflections.

---

As an extra let me point out that by the same line of reasoning all the reflections of $D_{2n}$ become conjugates in $D_{4n}$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126355/11619) for a discussion of this phenomenon in the case $n=4$.

---

And a very different way of looking at it:

The group $D_{2n}$ is defined by generators and relations as 
$$D_{2n}=\langle a, b\mid a^2=b^2=(ab)^n=1\rangle.$$

If $n$ is even this implies that we get four homomorphisms from $D_{2n}\to C_2=\{\pm1\}$ by arbitrarily mapping $a\mapsto \pm1$, $b\mapsto \pm1$. Because $C_2$ is abelian all the conjugates are mapped to same elements in all those homomorphisms. Therefore $a^ib^j$ and
$a^kb^\ell$ can be conjugates only if $i\equiv k$ and $j\equiv\ell\pmod2$.

OTOH if $n$ is odd, then any homomorphism $D_{2n}\to C_2$ must map $ab\mapsto1$, so the images of $a$ and $b$ are equal. Thus the determinant (sending both $a,b$ to $-1$ is the only non-trivial homomorphism from $D_{2n}$ to $C_2$ in this case.

Combining this with the bit about conjugates of reflections being reflections also allows you to identify the conjugacy classes.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of $D_{2n}$ are geometric transformations of the plane, leaving an $n$-gon fixed. So it makes sense for an element of $D_{2n}$ to be a reflection.

A conjugacy class of a reflection is a conjugacy class of an element which is a reflection. :-)

Comment: My main issue is that, looking at $D_{6}$ (order 6), shouldn't this have 3 conjugacy classes since there are 3 different reflections?

Comment: Well, the conjugacy classes of two different elements may well be equal!

Comment: There are 3 ways of swapping 2 vertices of a triangle by reflection, so isn't this 3 distinct ccls?

Comment: You are counting reflections, **not** conjugacy classes of reflections.

Comment: Make a list of all reflections and then for each of them write down the conlugacy class. Count how many *distinct* conjugacy classes you got.

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague attempt to inspire geometric intuition, rather than a rigorous demonstration of the point.

Think about the conjugacy classes of the dihedral group as symmetries of a polygon. Thinking geometrically, you might see that conjugating a reflection with a rotation leaves the reflection altered by an even number of vertices.

If there are $2n$ vertices conjugation keeps the parity the same. If there are $2n+1$ vertices, you go twice round, hitting all the vertices.

Comment: Hm. Thinking about conjugacy classes as «symmetries of the polygon» is probably a bad idea, really. The actual elements of the group are the symmetries of the polygon, so *they* should be thought of as symmetries of the polygon, because they are! Conjugacy classes are, if you insist, classes of symmtries of the polygon: two symmetrices which are in the same class are "similar" (in a sense made precise precisely by the definition of conjugacy class!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I mentioned it because it works for me. A polygon size $2n$ has a pair of polygons size $n$ inside it. Either it works for you or it doesn't. If it does't, well find another way.

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand at all what you say in what you wrote (for example, I don't really understand what you mean by «a rotation leaves the reflection alterned by an even number of times») nor what these two polygons of size $n$ you mention in your comment are, but thinking of conjugacy classes as symmetries of a polygon will most certainly class with pretty much everything.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Where there is an even number of vertices there is a parity which is preserved or exchanged by every element of the group. Conjugation exchanges parity twice (or keeps it the same both times) i.e. keeps it the same. Apologies if the original post was unclear about this.